# Aggregate CSV data by matching fields

Tags: go

Hello I am in need of some help, I have a csv file parsing that into a struct using gocsv, I need to range over the slices of that struct and combine the DeductionCodes of each slice that has a matching EmployeeNumber,

This is the csv struct.

```
type csvInput struct {
    EmployeeNumber string `json:"employeeNumber" csv:"Employee #"`
    DeductionCode  string `json:"deductionCode" csv:"Deduction Code"`
    Unit           string `json:"unit" csv:"Unit"`
    Amount         string `json:"amount" csv:"Amount"`
}
```

This here is what I am attempting to do, I need to join all the deductionCodes into an array for EACH slice that has a matching employeeNumber,

```
var payTypes []string
    for _, csv := range csvData {
        for _, c := range csvData {
            if csv.EmployeeNumber == c.EmployeeNumber {
                if csv.DeductionCode == c.DeductionCode {
                    payTypes = append(payTypes, c.DeductionCode)
                    jsonData, _ := json.Marshal(payTypes)
                    println(string(jsonData))
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is a sample of the csv file, Mind you I discard most of these fields from the csv itself

```
Employee #,Employee Name,Deduction Code,Description,HED,Unit,Ceridian Amount,New Calculation,Amount,Company Matched T / F,Calculated Worked Hours T/F
1362,USER 1,LINSTAXBEN 364,Life Insurance Taxable Benefit,364,$,18.31,16.90,16.90,,
1362,USER 1,AD&DTAXBEN 366,AD &D taxable benefit,366,$,0.19,0.18,0.18,,
1362,USER 1,PENS COMP 550,Company Pension (Non Union),550,%,5.00,130.52,5.00,T,T
1362,USER 1,FT DENTALF 641,Dental F FT,641,$,32.78,30.26,30.26,,
1362,USER 1,LTD 660,Long Term Disability,660,$,38.97,35.97,35.97,,
1362,USER 1,RRSP 720,RRSP,720,$,75.00,75.00,75.00,,
1362,USER 1,DON CLOC 761,CLOC Donations,761,$,2.00,2.00,2.00,,
1362,USER 1,SOC 770,Social Club,770,$,2.00,2.00,2.00,,
8113,USER 2,LINSTAXBEN 364,Life Insurance Taxable Benefit,364,$,11.58,10.69,10.69,,
8113,USER 2,AD&DTAXBEN 366,AD &D taxable benefit,366,$,0.12,0.11,0.11,,
8113,USER 2,MSPP PENSF 552,MSPP Pension FT,552,%,5.00,82.86,5.00,T,T
8113,USER 2,Union DUES 580,Union Dues,580,%,1.50,26.93,1.50,,T
8113,USER 2,FT DENTALF 641,Dental F FT,641,$,32.78,30.26,30.26,,
8113,USER 2,LTD 660,Long Term Disability,660,$,38.97,35.97,35.97,,
```

Running the above double range I know is long way from being correct, as it is just appending each deductionCode from BOTH employees, what I need is to parse ALL Employee Number 1362 into 1 struct slice with a deductioncode array, then ALL of Employee Number 8113 into a different slice with their deduction codes as an array.

If anyone needs to see more code just let me know. And apologies I am very new to golang and I am sure there is a much better way to accomplish what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need a set of unique employees, each with an array of deduction codes.  I'm making the assumption that the other properties will be the same for each employee record in the csv.  I like to use a `map` for this in go, because you can easily check whether the employee exists.  I think you'll also want to declare a separate type for your employees:

```
type Employee struct {
    Number, Unit, Amount string
    DeductionCodes       []string
}
```

And you might want to use this opportunity to convert the other values to types that make more sense.

Then:

```
employees := make(map[string]*Employee)

for _, csv := range csvData {
    if _, ok := employees[csv.EmployeeNumber]; !ok {
        employees[csv.EmployeeNumber] = &Employee{
            Number:         csv.EmployeeNumber,
            Unit:           csv.Unit,
            Amount:         csv.Amount,
            DeductionCodes: make([]string, 0, 1),
        }
    }
    e := employees[csv.EmployeeNumber]
    e.DeductionCodes = append(e.DeductionCodes, csv.DeductionCode)
}
```

So, if the employee number has already been encountered, you just add the deduction code to the existing employee.  Otherwise, you create a new one, then add it.

Comment: So okay tried that, I apologize again as I am very new to golang, I changed that range around to your above suggestion, I do not need Unit or Amount for this particular step as I will be using the EmployeeNumber & DeductionCode array as part of a mongo aggregate lookup for the _id's of them.

But putting just a simple json.Marshal after the range to see what it looks like, it is not adding anything to the deductionCodes array, its blank
{"1362":{"number":"1362","deductionCodes":[""]},"8113":{"number":"8113","deductionCodes":[""]}}

Comment: I've edited my answer to use a pointer to Employee.  I think that is probably the issue that you are seeing.

Comment: So now its complaining:
cannot use &(Employee literal) (value of type *Employee) as Employee value in assignment.

This is where I struggle a lot still, on how and what to use and when lol, this is import app number 3 for me and its getting the better of me. And yes what you said above each row will be the same layout so your assumption was correct.

Comment: Sorry - forgot to make the slice contain pointers to Employee as well.  The error tells you!

Comment: Thank you good sir, that works, learned something new so thanks again.

Comment: Ohh sorry one more question, the first string is in the array is blank, is there a way to trim that? 

`{"1362":{"number":"1362","deductionCodes":["","LINSTAXBEN 364","AD\u0026DTAXBEN 366","PENS COMP 550","FT DENTALF 641","LTD 660","RRSP 720","DON CLOC 761","SOC 770"]},"8113":{"number":"8113","deductionCodes":["","LINSTAXBEN 364","AD\u0026DTAXBEN 366","MSPP PENSF 552","Union DUES 580","FT DENTALF 641","LTD 660"]}}`, And yes I know I have to convert the & symbol to correct the output of AD &D taxable benefit

Comment: One more edit from me: had args to make backwards.  I've changed it to start with length 0 and cap 1.